# How to automatically update a tkinter ui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, page-refresh

I'm trying to make an UI in python with tkinter. I want it to show the very volatile value of something in the right corner (I'm getting the value through an api). This value can changes almost every second so I want to be sure it's up to date. I could make a button that refresh the ui but that's not really cool for the user. My question is how can I automatically refresh the value in the ui every x seconds with tkinter or is it isn't possible what's a better solution.

Comment: You need to give us a minimal working example. You can use `<tkinter.Tk>.after(time_in_ms, <your function>)`. That will call your function after the delay you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `Thread` that is running in the background and use `StringVar()` to update the value every x seconds in tkinter.

Example code that updates the time:

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import datetime
import time

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # Make a StringVar that will contain the value
        self.value = tk.StringVar()

        # Make a label that will show the value of self.value
        self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.value).pack()


        # Make a thread that will run outside the tkinter program
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.show_time)

        # set daemon to True (This means that the thread will stop when you stop the tkinter program)
        self.thread.daemon = True

        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        tk.Button(self, text="Click me", command=lambda: print("Hello World")).pack()

    def show_time(self):
        # The thread will execute this function in the background, so you need to while loop to update the value of self.value
        while True:

            # Get the time (in your case, you need to get the api data)
            data = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('Time: %H:%M:%S, Milliseconds: %f')

            # Update the StringVar variable
            self.value.set(data)

            # Pause the while loop with 1 second, so you can set an interval to update your value
            time.sleep(1)

# rest of your code.

root = SampleApp()
root.mainloop()
```